# Yii2 RESTful: Content Negotiation languages not work

Tags: php, yii2, response, yii-rest, yii2-api

I implemented a structure of API Rest with the models in Yii2. Everything works great for actions (index, create, update etc ...) and methods (GET, POST, PUT etc ..) but I have a problem with the `ContentNegotiator` class.
Specifically, if I pass as a parameter of GET the language in which the response is to be translated, this is ignored.
According to the documentation for setting the language of response we need to set allowed languages of `ContentNegotiator` (look at my `behaviors()`) and make a request like this:

http://localhost/api/v1/users?_lang=it-IT

But the response continues to be in English. Why??? Nothing against the English =)

This is my `ActiveController` child class that extend from `yii\rest\Controller`.

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

class AActiveController extends ActiveController
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['verbFilter'] = [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => $this->verbs(),
        ];
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['languages'] = [
            'en-EN',
            'it-IT',
            'de-DE',
            'ru-RU',
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
...
```

*N.B.*: I debug through `yii\filters\ContentNegotiator` class of the framework and at this point the app language is set correctly but the response is always in English.

[negotiate() public method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html#negotiate()-detail)

```
public function negotiate()
{
    $request = $this->request ?: Yii::$app->getRequest();
    $response = $this->response ?: Yii::$app->getResponse();
    if (!empty($this->formats)) {
        $this->negotiateContentType($request, $response);
    }
    if (!empty($this->languages)) {
        Yii::$app->language = $this->negotiateLanguage($request);
    }
    debug(Yii::$app->language); // result OK!: it-IT 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when write "But the response continues to be in English." ContentNegotiator can only set lang app field. If you need translating you should do it yourself.

Comment: I mean that the answer has not been translated into Italian

Comment: Framework cant translate your custom data.

Comment: I did not speak about custom data.

Comment: I mean the default messages of response, like "Method not allowed" or "Page not found"

Comment: Do you have files in `.../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages` ? If not seems you should use `yii message` command Docs: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html)

Comment: Of course is under the framework repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160722/discussion-between-torv-and-alvarofvr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some build-in errors not translated, for example `yii\rest\Action:103` throws `throw new NotFoundHttpException("Object not found: $id")` its not translated. You have different ways to solve this problem:

1. Good way. Extend this Action and throw correct exception with translate
2. Bad way. Edit framework file itself.
3. Best way. Create patch to framework and send to maintainers.

For more information about i18n [see documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html).